# Can a Sego Palm skip a growing season?

Tags: shrubs, planting, growth

I planted a Sego Palm too close to a sidewalk . After years of trimming, I finally cut off at ground level . The trunk was about 42" , so I dug a 36" hole and planted it.  This happened last fall , the 5 big fronds are green and look healthy, but it did not put out any new growth ( New growth is in May for Zone 9). So I wonder if it skipped a year of growth or is dying ?

Comment: Are you sure this wasn't a plastic plant?  This is too weird.  No way should this plant have made it this long.  I can't even think of an answer for you.  This just isn't natural.  Maybe we will all learn something about this plant.  Not a palm but a cycad...still makes no sense this plant is still alive other than it is able to keep water in the vascular system. https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/ornamental/trees/sago-palm/how-to-care-for-sago-palms.htm

Comment: We have had a pretty wet spring and sprinklers run in dry periods. It is in filtered shade.

Comment: Sago 'Palms' hate wet feet.  Not sure what pH they thrive with but next to a concrete walkway might be worth looking into for higher pH levels.  Blacksmith, I just have to tell you I am amazed this plant still has life!  Maybe you and your plants have a great connection, communication but to have this very mature Sago 'Palm' still alive since fall is truly needing to be in Guiness World of Records...or  however you spell it.  Something is very wrong or very right.  I am entranced with this...what made you dig a 3' hole to bury the trunk of this guy without roots?  Come on...gotta tell!

Comment: I have acidic sand. Camellias do well, although I did loose a couple this year to root rot ( wet spring),

Answer (score 4):

If you cut the palm at the ground level and then replanted it I would imagine it is probably in shock from having its entire root system removed.  My guess is the reason you didn't see any new growth this year is because the plant put all of the effort into growing a new roots.  I'm the kind of gardener that won't pull out a plant until its 100% dead so I would leave it where it is and see what happens next year.  The fact that the original fronds are still green and healthy is a good sign. A layer of compost will likely help the plant recover from the transplant shock and give it the nutrient it needs for new roots/fronds. I've read that Sego Palms benefit from regular fertilizer applications but I would read up on this more to figure out how often, how much and specifically which nutrients benefit Sego Palms.